# Member 'SoundManager.PlaySound(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#

#this is my SoundManager I'm try to add a sound in to my unity game project error said "Member 'SoundManager.PlaySound(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead" how i can fix it Thank you

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class SoundManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static AudioClip footstep1Sound, footstep2Sound, footstep3Sound, footstep4Sound, footstep5Sound, jumpSound, powerupSound, blackgroundSound;
        static AudioSource audioSrc;
        
        void Start()
        {
            footstep1Sound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("footstep_grass_000");
            footstep2Sound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("footstep_grass_001");
            footstep3Sound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("footstep_grass_002");
            footstep4Sound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("footstep_grass_003");
            footstep5Sound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("footstep_grass_004");
            jumpSound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("jump");
            powerupSound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("powerUp");
            blackgroundSound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Mishief Stroll");
    
            audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSrc.PlayOneShot(jumpSound);
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            
        }
    
        public static void PlaySound(string clip)
        {
            switch (clip)
            {
                case "powerUp":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(powerupSound);
                    break;
                case "jump":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(jumpSound);
                    break;
                case "footstep_grass_000":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(footstep1Sound);
                    break;
                case "footstep_grass_001":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(footstep2Sound);
                    break;
                case "footstep_grass_002":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(footstep3Sound);
                    break;
                case "footstep_grass_003":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(footstep4Sound);
                    break;
                case "footstep_grass_004":
                    audioSrc.PlayOneShot(footstep5Sound);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
     #This is my error code line 
    
    soundManager.PlaySound("jump");
```

#it my first time to share this why it to hard to post in stackover flow lol

Answer (score 2):

Your *PlaySound()* method is `static`. You need to either call it like this:

```cs
SoundManager.PlaySound("jump");
```

Or remove the static keyword:

```cs
public void PlaySound(string clip)
{
   //...
}
```

You cannot call static methods on non-static instances

Comment: My code is now done but sound sill mute can u help sir

Comment: that's a separate problem, isn't it?